# Two html form actions

Tags: php, html, forms

Is it possible to create two form actions? One should action a .php page and one should action a script on the same page.

```
<form method="post" action="">

// Input fields here

<input type="submit" name="calculate" value="Calculate price">
       // Form should perform the calculation script below (not attached here)

<input type="submit" name="order" value="Order">
       // Form should perform the action 'order.php'

</form>
```

Searched for a long time, but could not find a solution. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: You would need two different forms

Comment: Dynamically reassign the action using JavaScript, triggered by an onclick event (you'd need to disable the form submission by something like onsubmit calling a function that returns false)?

Comment: Looking at the code, the first button just executes a script right? This does not need to be an input of type submit. Just run the js on click.

Answer (score 4):

If you want a button in a form to do something other than submit the form set its type to `button`

```
<input type="button" name="calculate" value="Calculate price">
```

then attach a click handler to the button to run your script.

Comment: I've changed the input type of the Calcute button to 'button', but now the script does not work anymore? With the input set to "submit" it did work (both buttons by the way)?

Comment: Can you clarify that when you say "perform the calculation script" you are referring to a javascript function?

Comment: @KevinHamer if you have to attach a click handler to the button, are you using a submit handler to detect the button press?

Comment: Trying to get this right.. How would my code then look like?

Comment: Think I already got it... Will post the correct code as soon as everything works!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an event that will lead to this change, yes but with javascript.
Example:

```
 $('select#actions').on('change', function(){
   var action = $('#actions').find(":selected").val();
   $('#someForm').attr("action", action + '.php');//or whatever is the route
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function SubmitForm()
   {
   if(document.pressed == 'Calculate price')
   {
      document.myform.action ="calculate.php";
   }
   else
      if(document.pressed == 'Order')
      {
         document.myform.action ="order.php";
      }
      return true;
   }
</script>
<form method="post" onsubmit="return SubmitForm();">

 // Input fields here

   <input type="submit" name="operation" onclick="document.pressed=this.value" value="Calculate price">
   // Form should perform the calculation script below (not attached here)

   <input type="submit" name="operation" onclick="document.pressed=this.value" value="Order">
   // Form should perform the action 'order.php'

</form>
```

So when you submits, trigger a function that capture your button value and set form action.

In this case, you can put your calculation script in a php file.